# android not honoring trigger.io's tabs.openWithOptions for server side redirect

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, trigger.io

I've got some basic trigger.io code to open a modal dialog for oauth2 authentication:

```
var url_auth = "http://10.0.0.70/oauth2/authorize";
var oauth_client_id = "123";
var oauth_redirect_uri = "http://done.com/oauth2/complete";

forge.tabs.openWithOptions({
    url: url_auth + "?response_type=token&client_id="+ oauth_client_id + "&redirect_url=" + oauth_redirect_uri,
    pattern: oauth_redirect_uri + "*",
    title: "Authorizing"
}, function(data) { ... });
```

When the user isn't authenticated, the server redirects to `http://10.0.0.70/users` to present a login form.

Running the code in an iOS6 simulator yields the correct result:

- open modal dialog
- server redirects to login form, presented within the dialog
- user can authenticate
- server redirects to oauth_redirect_uri which trigger catches and closes the dialog

When I run in an android simulator, the initial page is loaded, but then the app crashes.

- I see the /oauth2/authorize url being processed on the server
- all I see in the debug dialog is "subView load `http://10.0.0.70:3000/users`"

The more details around the error are (nothing after this in logs):

```
[DEBUG] Native call tabs.open with task.params: {"url":"http://10.0.0.70:3000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=123&redirect_url=http://www.diveboatbuddy.com/oauth2/complete","pattern":"^http://www.diveboatbuddy.com/oauth2/complete.*$","title":"Authorizing"}
[INFO] Displaying modal view.
[DEBUG] Returned: {"content":null,"callid":"0F7BA94D-08AD-439D-B44F-80BB22540CD4","status":"success"}
[DEBUG] Native call logging.log with task.params: {"message":"[FORGE] 'Successfully subscribed for push notifications'","level":20}
[INFO] [FORGE] 'Successfully subscribed for push notifications'
[DEBUG] Returned: {"content":null,"callid":"030EF36D-C17F-42E8-8F9E-0221A40153D1","status":"success"}
[INFO] subView load http://10.0.0.70:3000/users
```

So it looks like the server has redirected correctly, but the trigger.io app isn't rendering the new server page.

adb logcat output of the problem:

```
D/Forge   (  394): Returned: {"content":null,"callid":"03F62CF7-8B33-425C-ABD5-2BA64565B789","status":"success"}
D/dalvikvm(  394): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 349 objects / 24336 bytes in 41ms
I/Forge   (  394): subView load http://10.0.0.70:3000/users
D/AndroidRuntime(  394): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  394): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.removeJavascriptInterface
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at io.trigger.forge.android.modules.tabs.ModalView$2$3.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(ModalView.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:216)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  394):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(   59):   Force finishing activity io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141/io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity
I/ARMAssembler(   59): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x3446c0:0x34477c] in 5998000 ns
W/ActivityManager(   59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43f928a8 io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141/io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity}
I/Process (  394): Sending signal. PID: 394 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   59): Process io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141 (pid 394) has died.
W/ActivityManager(   59): Scheduling restart of crashed service io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141/com.parse.PushService in 5000ms
I/WindowManager(   59): WIN DEATH: Window{44002988 io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141/io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity paused=false}
I/ActivityManager(   59): Start proc io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141 for service io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141/com.parse.PushService: pid=422 uid=10036 gids={1015, 3003}
```

Has anyone come across this issue.  Is there a work around or a bug?

Comment: When you say crash, what exactly do you mean? Could you give us the log output all around that "subView load" part? The relevant part of adb logcat output would be great too, if possible...

Comment: I mean it crashes :)  The application stops and a dialog comes up that says "Sorry!  The application (process.io.trigger.forge1979a236289211e2bbe612313d31f141) has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again"

Comment: What happens if you openWithOptions on your /users URL directly? Can you run adb logcat in a terminal and update your question with the stack trace towards the end when the crash occurs?

Comment: /users works fine when called in the openWithOptions, also works fine when called directly from a web browser, and as mentioned above, the iOS version has no issues.  adb logcat debug above.

Comment: Right, got it - I've recreated here: problem is page changes in modal views on Android devices <3.0. A fix will be in our next platform version: will update here.

Comment: do you have an ETA on that version release date?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in v1.4.34 of the Trigger.io platform: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-34.